# Why my containerized Java application seems to be running on 1 CPU, when the host machine, running the Kubernetes, runs on a 4 Core CPU?

Tags: java

Today when I check my service run in Kubernetes v1.15.2 using [arthas](https://github.com/alibaba/arthas) dashboard, It shows the CPU is 1. now the Java version is OpenJDK 1.8.0_265:

[image]

my host machine is 4 Core 16GB, is this tell me the progrom using 1 Core? my Namespace did not give resource limit and the Deployment did not give resource limit too. If not, how to see the program using how much Core exactly? this is my startup entry:

```
ENTRYPOINT exec java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xmx1024M -Xms256M \
                -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,suspend=n,server=y,address=5009 \
                -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/data/dump \
                -javaagent:/opt/skywalking/agent/skywalking-agent.jar \
                -Dskywalking.agent.service_name=soa-robot-service \
                -Dskywalking.collector.backend_service=oap:11800 \
                -jar /root/soa-robot-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Comment: Trying to edit your title *how java run in container determin CPU core in kubernetes*, but can't really come up with exact name what you might have been meaning.. could you edit this, please?

Comment: I have changed the title @GiorgiTsiklauri

Comment: I have edited it. I hope this reflects your point.

Comment: Which part exactly you don't understand?

Comment: Does your application uses multiple CPUs _outside_ the container?

Comment: I am always run in container, did not give CPU number in any stage@KevinBoone

Comment: Then the container you use is already a single-core container?